# Should HTTP PUT create a resource if it does not exist?

Tags: rest, http, put

Lets suppose that someone performs a `PUT` request on my endoint:

```
/resources/{id}
```

However there is not resource with the given id stored in my PostgreSQL database.

According to the [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), I should create the resource if I am capable to:

> The `PUT` method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing on the origin server. If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI.

Would be okay to create the resource with the provided id? As manually assigning ids on database insert is not the best practice.

Should I return a `404` error if the creation of the resource is not possible?

Comment: Perhaps there are two aspects in your question:
1. Whether PUT can create non-existent resources.
2. What scheme you should use to generate database ID.

I think answering the second one(yourself) is key to deciding on the options the RFC gives you.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

First of all, you are using an **obsolete** document: The RFC 2616 is no longer relevant nowadays and anyone using such document as reference should *stop right away*.

Quoting [Mark Nottingham](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead) who, at the time of writing, co-chairs the IETF HTTP and QUIC Working Groups:

> **Don’t use RFC2616**. Delete it from your hard drives, bookmarks, and burn (or responsibly recycle) any copies that are printed out.

The old RFC 2616 has been supplanted by the following documents that, together, define the HTTP/1.1 protocol:

- [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230): Message Syntax and Routing
- [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231): Semantics and Content
- [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232): Conditional Requests
- [RFC 7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233): Range Requests
- [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234): Caching
- [RFC 7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235): Authentication

If you are looking for methods, status codes and headers definitions, then the  [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) is the document you should refer to.

---

Having said that, let's go back to your question.

> Should HTTP `PUT` create a resource if it does not exist?

It depends.

But, if your application generates resource identifiers on behalf of the client, as you mentioned in your question, then you should use [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) instead of [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) for creating resources.

Some parts of the [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) method definition are quoted below. The last sentence seems to be the most relevant to you (highlight is mine), supporting what I've just mentioned above:

> [**4.3.4.  PUT**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)
>
> The `PUT` method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.  [...]
>
> If the target resource does not have a current representation and the `PUT` successfully creates one, then the origin server MUST inform the user agent by sending a `201` (Created) response.  If the target resource does have a current representation and that representation is successfully modified in accordance with the state of the enclosed representation, then the origin server MUST send either a `200` (OK) or a `204` (No Content) response to indicate successful completion of the request. [...]
>
> Proper interpretation of a `PUT` request presumes that the user agent knows which target resource is desired.  **A service that selects a proper URI on behalf of the client, after receiving a state-changing request, SHOULD be implemented using the `POST` method rather than `PUT`.** [...]

---

> Should I return a `404` error if the creation of the resource is not possible?

That's seems to be an accurate status code to be returned, as no representation has been found for the requested resource:

> [**6.5.4.  404 Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)
>
> The `404` (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. [...]

---

Now, for the sake of completeness, find below some relevant quotes on the [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) method definition, which should be used to create resources in the scenario described in your question:

> [**4.3.3.  POST**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)
>
> The `POST` method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics. For example, `POST` is used for the following functions (among others):
>
> [...]
>
> - Creating a new resource that has yet to be identified by the origin server;
>
> [...]
>
> If one or more resources has been created on the origin server as a result of successfully processing a `POST` request, the origin server SHOULD send a `201` (Created) response containing a `Location` header field that provides an identifier for the primary resource created and a representation that describes the status of the request while referring to the new resource(s).

While the [`201`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2) status code indicates that a new resource has been created, the [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header indicate where the newly created resource is located. If no [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header is provided, then the client should assume that the resource is identified by the effective request URI:

> [**6.3.2. 201 Created**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2)
>
> The `201` (Created) status code indicates that the request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created. The primary resource created by the request is identified by either a `Location` header field in the response or, if no `Location` field is received, by the effective request URI. [...]

Comment: For the sake of keeping the high technical level of this answer: All the RFCs mentioned in this answer have been obsoleted.
RFC-9110 has obsoleted the following RFCs: RFC-7230, RFC-7231, RFC-7232, RFC-7233, RFC-7235.
RFC-9111 has obsoleted the following RFC: RFC-7234.

Comment: Should we not return a 204 No Content, if we cant find the item to update ?

Answer (score 4):

In short, it depends wheter the payload you want to store violates any constraint the server has for resources or not.

In general I'd say it should attempt it as the client explicitly expresses his intent to store that particular representation at the target URI. The server should though perform constraint checks before! Usually, in a real REST scenario though, the client should use URI that are provided by the server and not just chose any URI on its own. Thereby, a server should be in control of its namespace, as such using `PUT` to create resources is not recommended here by default.

With that being said, as `PUT` is idempotent while `POST` being not, some clients might want to benefit from this property. Here a [POST-PUT creation pattern](http://restalk-patterns.org/post-put.html) has evolved, where a client is attempting to create a new resource via `POST` until it receives a confirmation via a `Location` header in the response and afterwards attempts the update of that resource's state via `PUT`. This way the client can be sure that in case of transmission problems the representation was only created once. Depending on the stance, some people might consider the actual update of the resource as the actual resource creation, though as the client beforehand received the respective link, this is not quite the case.

Note that a server also has the right to transform the representation to something different if i.e. the server is configured to provide specific representations for certain URI endpoints. Think of uploading an image via PUT to a URI and the server embedds the image into a HTML page

Answer (score 2):

There's two questions embedded here: 1) should PUT try to create the resource and 2) what happens if it cant.

1)
The RFC linked by @cass says https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4:

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be
> created or replaced with the state defined by the representation
> enclosed in the request message payload.  A successful PUT of a given
> representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same
> target resource will result in an equivalent representation being
> sent in a 200 (OK) response.

Further, Mozilla's text  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT

> The HTTP PUT request method creates a new resource or replaces a representation of the target resource with the request payload.

Further, from the original RFC (that was replaced with the above test)  https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified version of the one residing on the origin server. If the Request-URI does not point to an existing resource, and that URI is capable of being defined as a new resource by the requesting user agent, the origin server can create the resource with that URI.

This is a bit anecdotal, but the Kubernetes API also carefully makes this distinction and informs it's users of PATCH if they really meant update: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#api-verbs

> For PUT requests, Kubernetes internally classifies these as either create or update based on the state of the existing object. An update is different from a patch; the HTTP verb for a patch is PATCH.

2
In terms of "what happens if it fails" I think the code depends on what went wrong:

- 400: it couldnt be created due to a bad payload
- 409: it couldnt be created due to a conflict - for example some field in the input JSON has some global uniqueness check on it
- 502/3 - it couldnt be created because it tried to call the database and it was dead

I'm not sure if 404 is the best code, becuase it doesnt tell the user anything about *why*.

Answer (score 2):

As for 2023 according to the [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110#name-put) `PUT` can create or replace the resource.

> 9.3.4. PUT
>
> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message content.